# Trying to save the output of a bc calculation into a variable in a bash script

Tags: bash, unix, bc

```
average=$(echo "scale=2;$combine/$num | bc")
```

This is my most recent attempt at it and it just saves scale=2;256/3 into average. I've tried so many different ways of wording it and I can't seem to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated. The bash script kicks off with a command to run the script in a ksh shell, if that matters at all.

Comment: The closing quote is misplaced, it should be: `average=$(echo "scale=2;$combine/$num" | bc)`

Comment: I'm am a worthless idiot. That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
average=$(bc <<< "scale=2;$combine/$num")
```

Or as the first comment says. You misplaced the quotation.

```
average=$(echo "scale=2;$combine/$num" | bc)
```